# Provider not updating value permanently

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

Yesterday I posted a question which is not yet solved.

Here you have a screenshot from the widget

[image]

The values 0 / 5 are

```
provider.numMensajesForoEsp16Vistos = 0
provider.numMensajesForoEsp16 = 5
```

Here you have the code for the widget at bottom right

```
   child: Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    children: [
    Text("${provider.numMensajesForoEsp16Vistos} / ${provider.numMensajesForoEsp16}",
    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16,  color: hexStringToColor( especialidad                                                                                .color_especialidad))),
     Padding(
     padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),child: Visibility(
visible: provider.numMensajesForoEsp16 > 
provider.numMensajesForoEsp16Vistos,
     child: Row( mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
     children: [Container(width: 15, height: 15,
     decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: Colors.red,  shape: BoxShape                                                                                      .circle), ), ], )
```

When clicking on the card, here you have the code:

```
    if (_esEsp) {
    print("nume mensajes descargados ${provider.numMensajesForoEsp16}");   
provider.cambiarNumeroMensajesForo16espVistos(provider.numMensajesForoEsp16);
    }
    if (!_esEsp) {provider.cambiarNumeroMensajesForo16engVistos(provider.numMensajesForoEng16);
    }
```

That code should update cambiarNumeroMensajesForo16espVistos to 5, as it is shown in the print output:

```
flutter: nume mensajes descargados 5
```

After clicking the card, the app opens another screen, and the if you click to go back to previous screen, the widgets is updated to the new values

[image]

But only for a couple of seconds, then it comes back to the state

[image]

Here you have the provider file:

```
class ForoProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  //VARIABLES
  
  int numMensajesForoEsp16 = 0;

  int numMensajesForoEng16 = 0;
 
  int numMensajesForoEsp16Vistos = 0;

  int numMensajesForoEng16Vistos = 0;

  void cambiarNumeroMensajesForo16esp (int s){
    numMensajesForoEsp16 = s;
    notifyListeners();
  }
 
  void cambiarNumeroMensajesForo16eng (int s){
    numMensajesForoEng16 = s;
    notifyListeners();
  }
  


  //vistos

  
  void cambiarNumeroMensajesForo16espVistos (int s){
    numMensajesForoEsp16Vistos = s;
    notifyListeners();
  }
 
  void cambiarNumeroMensajesForo16engVistos(int s){
    numMensajesForoEng16Vistos = s;
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

And here you have to top widget that includes Consumer

```
 Expanded(
                child: RefreshIndicator(
                  onRefresh: refresh,
                  child: Consumer<ForoProvider>(
                    builder: (context, provider, child) {
                      return Column(
```

I don´t know what is wrong or missing in order to permanently update the value for

```
provider.numMensajesForoEsp16Vistos
```

Comment: I am thinking how you've initialized the provider, or if you create new instance on 1st page/other page it will reset again.  It would be nice to have a full minimal code-snippet that will reproduce the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me (without access of the full code) that:

1 - the value resets: you might be creating your provider in the widget that generates the 1st card. This way, when you go back to it, the values are reseted.

2 - the value doesn't update: for the widget to update when the provider notifies, it has to be listening to the provider (context.watch, context.select or listen using AnimatedContainer). Alternatively you could use a setState after calling the provider.

Test sth like this:

```
// main_app.dart (or up in your widget tree):

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return ChangeNotifierProvider<ForoProvider>(
      create: (_) => ForoProvider(),
      child: const AppHome(),
    );

// app_home.dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  // Watch can be used either in stateless or statefull widgets
  // This lane will make sure to rebuild the widget every time a 
  // notifyListeners is sent.
  final foroProvider = context.watch<ForoProvider>();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your variable getting **reinitialised** when the ForoProvider() instant created or called.

```
class ForoProvider extends ChangeNotifier {

//VARIABLES  
int numMensajesForoEsp16 = 0;
int numMensajesForoEng16 = 0; 
int numMensajesForoEsp16Vistos = 0;
int numMensajesForoEng16Vistos = 0;

void cambiarNumeroMensajesForo16esp (int s){
  numMensajesForoEsp16 = s;
  notifyListeners();
}
. 
.
.
.
.
}
```

Try to initialise the variable above the class like.

```
//VARIABLES  
int numMensajesForoEsp16 = 0;
int numMensajesForoEng16 = 0; 
int numMensajesForoEsp16Vistos = 0;
int numMensajesForoEng16Vistos = 0;

class ForoProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
...
}
```